# How to configure Atom for Python?

Tags: linux, command-line, python, atom-editor

I installed atom-python-run for running python in Atom. But when I installed python extension in VS Code, then a massage came in that pylint not installed. And I clicked in install button. then a command appears in teminal,

```
/usr/bin/python3 -m pip install -U pylint --user
```

and pylint installed. But when I run python in Atom, a message appears.

```
Atom python-run:terminalerror: There was a problem in opening xterm.
```

Now, What is that --user, How can I remove pylint and how can I fix atom editor?

Comment: `pip help install`